# videogular crops video rather than resizing

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, videogular

I have a video with original size 1920x1080. I am using the css from the basic set up tutorial, but tried setting the default height in css to 1080:

```
.videogular-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1080px;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .videogular-container {
        width: 1170px;
        height: 658.125px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
    .videogular-container {
        width: 940px;
        height: 528.75px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
    .videogular-container {
        width: 728px;
        height: 409.5px;
    }
}
```

That seems to be the overflow thing - it just hides the rest of the video instead of actually resizing it.

In the config I have this set up:

```
width: 1920,
 height: 1080,      
 responsive: true,
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you able to provide a link to a live version of your project?

Comment: No, sorry. It's on my local server...

Comment: What Videogular version are you using? Width, height and responsive are parameters for versions older than 1.X.X. From version 1.X.X Videogular behaves always as a responsive video player and width and height are always 100%

Comment: It's 1.2.1 It is responsive - it resizes the video area depending on the screen width - the problem is it resizes the area (video container), rather than the video itself and as a result I see a cropped video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related with answer [Controls font/symbols missing - videogular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30145630/controls-font-symbols-missing-videogular/30166019#30166019)

You need to set the correct url for Videogular theme.

Answer (score 1):

This helps me.
Just put it on the CSS file where the video is.

```
video {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

With display as FLEX